# ELK - cluster_block_exception error while upgrading from version 8.8.0 to 8.8.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

---

Hello,

I wanted to upgrade an Elasticsearch/Kibana cluster from version 8.8.0 to 8.8.1.

During the update I got an error because the node was 86% full.

After enlarging the disk space, the update resumed and completed without error.

However, since then I've been getting this error in the kibana logs:

```
cause\":{\"type\":\"cluster_block_exception\",\"reason\":\"index [.kibana_task_manager_8.6.2_001] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];},}"status":403}
```

Do you have any idea what causes this error and how to correct it?

Best regards,

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get from `GET .kibana_task_manager_8.6.2_001/_settings` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion Val.

Thank you Val for your suggestion.

The solution was:

Resolution with a user having the rights to modify a system index:

[image]